# Filter and merge points from two dataframe within a specific distance in Geopandas

Tags: python, pandas, geometry, geopandas

For two GeoPandas dataframes as follows:

**df1:**

```
     id  sMiddleLng  sMiddleLat  p1_sum  p2_sum  \
0  325782  109.255034   34.691754     0.0     0.0   
1   84867  107.957177   33.958289     0.0     0.0   
2   13101  107.835338   33.739493     0.0     0.0   
3   92771  109.464280   33.980666     0.0     0.0   
4   86609  108.253830   33.963262     0.0     0.0   

                            geometry  
0  POINT (109.255033915 34.69175367)  
1  POINT (107.957177305 33.95828929)  
2    POINT (107.8353377 33.73949313)  
3   POINT (109.46428019 33.98066616)  
4  POINT (108.253830245 33.96326193)
```

**df2:**

```
     fnid  sMiddleLng  sMiddleLat  p1_sum  p2_sum  \
0  361104  102.677887   36.686408     0.0     0.0   
1  276307  103.268356   36.425372     0.0     0.0   
2  334778  103.242125   36.605224     0.0     0.0   
3  205223  104.186869   36.206637     0.0     0.0   
4  167892  104.387566   36.091905     0.0     0.0   

                                 geometry  
0  POINT (102.67788654685 36.68640780045)  
1  POINT (103.26835590025 36.42537187675)  
2   POINT (103.2421246007 36.60522388845)  
3    POINT (104.1868687253 36.2066370049)  
4   POINT (104.38756565315 36.0919047206)
```

How can find and merge all the points from another similar Geodataframe `df2`, to `df1` based on `id` and `geometry`, which have distance less `10 km` to between points in `df1` and `df2`? Thanks.

Function to calculate distance:

```
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt

def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)
    """
    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

    # haversine formula 
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
    r = 6371 # Radius of earth in kilometers. Use 3956 for miles
    return c * r
```

Comment: Do not use `math.cos/sin...` instead use `np.cos/sin...` which allow you to vectorize over `np.array` and `pd.DataFrame/Series`.

Comment: Thanks. Any ideas how to realize the output I want in the original post?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My suggestion follows the following logic:

1. reproject both `GeoDataFrame` to a projection using metres as units such as WebMercator
2. temporarily create a buffer of 10 km around the points in one of the data sets
3. use sjoin to find/merge overlapping points

This could be implemented as follows:

```
# Assuming your data uses WGS84 projection. only use the following line if crs has not been initialised
df1.crs = df2.crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'} 

# Now convert the Dataframes to WebMercator
df2 = df2.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:3857'})
df1 = df1.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:3857'})

# Create a buffer with a radius of 10000 meters around each point in df2
df2.geometry = df2.geometry.buffer(10000)

# Join the two Dataframes and convert back to original projection
df3 = gpd.sjoin(df1, df2, how='left', op='intersects', lsuffix='_df1', rsuffix='_df2')
df3.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:4326'}) # or whatever was used originally
```

Now you have the info on the joined points in one handy `GeoDataFrame`. In case of the given data, there were no points in `df2` within 10km of a point in `df1`.

Also, I'm not entirely sure in what form you want to have your merged data, so just adapt to your needs accordingly.

Comment: Thanks but sorry, I got this error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_crs'`, any ideas?

Comment: Hi, the error message indicates that your dfs are regular `pandas` `DataFrame`s. Convert them to `geopandas` `GeoDataFrame`s like this: `df1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df1)` where `gpd`is the `geopandas` package. Note that the Points in the `geometry` column need to be `shapely` Point objects (sometimes when you import the data from elsewhere they are just text strings). If you need a hint at how to convert those, let me know.